# German Speech Support in Bot Framework

Tags: botframework, chatbot

is the Speech Support in Bot Framework also available for the german language?

kind regards

Comment: Are you using .NET or Node SDK for BotBuilder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you read through [this blog](https://blog.botframework.com/2017/06/26/Speech-To-Text/) in the section "Cross platform speech support in your app using the DirectLine channel" there is this code snippet:

```
_botClient = new Microsoft.Bot.Client.BotClient(
    BotConnection.DirectLineSecret,
    BotConnection.ApplicationName
){
    // We used the Cognitive Services Speech-To-Text API, with speech priming support as the speech recognizer as well as the Text-To-Speech API.
    // Alternate/custom speech recognizer & synthesizer implementation are supported as well.
    SpeechRecognizer = new CognitiveServicesSpeechRecognizer(BotConnection.BingSpeechKey),
    SpeechSynthesizer = new CognitiveServicesSpeechSynthesizer(BotConnection.BingSpeechKey, Microsoft.Bot.Client.SpeechSynthesis.CognitiveServices.VoiceNames.Jessa_EnUs)
};
```

in theory you could replace this line:

```
SpeechSynthesizer = new CognitiveServicesSpeechSynthesizer(BotConnection.BingSpeechKey, Microsoft.Bot.Client.SpeechSynthesis.CognitiveServices.VoiceNames.Jessa_EnUs)
```

with any synthesizer you want.  So assuming there is a German synthesizer out there, the answer to your question is yes.